# pandas groupby, difference between top and bottom group members

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Assume I have `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
                  'V1': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                  'V2': [7,8,9,19,11,12]})
```

I want to create a new column `V3`, indicating the difference between `V2` for the "top" group member, and `V1` for the "bottom" group member. The result would look like:

```
    ID  V1  V2  V3
0   a   1   7   6
1   b   2   8   4
2   b   3   9   4
3   b   4   19  4
4   c   5   11  5
5   c   6   12  5
```

I tried something like this, which doesn't work:

```
df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.head(1).V2-x.tail(1).V1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `first` and `last` and subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df['V3'] = df.groupby('ID').V2.transform('first').sub(df.groupby('ID').V1.transform('last'))
```

Your solution shoud be changed by selecting by positions and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.V2.iat[0]-x.V1.iat[-1])
df['V3'] = df['ID'].map(s)
print (df)
  ID  V1  V2  V3
0  a   1   7   6
1  b   2   8   4
2  b   3   9   4
3  b   4  19   4
4  c   5  11   5
5  c   6  12   5
```